# How to make the following complicated table in Latex?

Tags: tables

[image]

Suppose you can use {amsmath} package.
I write a one by myself, but some details are not very good. E.g. in the following Table(show only a small part), the word "Stage" is not in vertical-center as the original table shown in the above.

[image]

My code is here:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{small}
\begin{sc}
\begin{tabular}{llp{1.5cm}cp{2cm}}
\toprule
\textit{\textbf{Stage}}-1 &  & ACPF \newline converge & Over-limit Lines \\
\cline{1-1}
    & \textit{Generation}-1 & $\surd$  & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sc}
\end{small}
\end{center}
```

Comment: What is the `sc` environment?

Comment: Any news? Can you extend your table with some more rows example that its context become more apparent?

Comment: sc is a environment provided by a conference.

Comment: I post my finalized code below. Any comments are welcomed!

Comment: @ZPascal Please consider the remarks in @ Zarkos answer. Instead of `\begin{small}....\end{small}` use `\small`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your table is not so complex, but let me say frankly, I would reconsider it design again
- Context of your table is unknown, so it is hart to advise some its  improvements
- Your code example use unknown environment `sc`, probably you like to have text in the small caps shape
- Environment `\small` doesn't exist, to have small font size you should use `\small` command after `\begin{center}`
- The use of the `\makecell` macro from the package with the same name can improve formatting of column headers
- The following MWE (Minimal Working Example) only repair and slightly improve your code fragment ...

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{center}
  \small\scshape         % <---
  \begin{tabular}{lllcl} % <---
      \toprule
  \textit{\textbf{Stage}}-1
      &                       &   \makecell{ACPF\\ converge}
                                          &   \makecell{Over-limit\\ Lines} \\  % <---
  \cline{1-1}
      & \textit{Generation}-1 &   $\surd$ & 0 \\
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```latex
\begin{center}
\begin{small}
\begin{sc}
\begin{tabular}{m{1.5cm}lccl}
\toprule
%\textit{\textbf{Stage}}-1 &  & ACPF \newline converge & Over-limit Lines \\
\textit{\textbf{Stage}}-1
    &                       &   \makecell{ACPF \\ Converge}
                                        &   \makecell{Over-limit \\ Lines} \\
\cline{1-1}
    & \textit{Generation}-1 & Yes  & 0 \\ 
%\hhline{====}
\hline
\textit{\textbf{Stage}}-2
    &                       &   \makecell{ACPF \\ Converge}
                                        &   \makecell{Over-limit \\ Lines} \\
\cline{1-1}
    & \textit{Generation}-2 & Yes  & 0 \\ 
\hhline{====} \\
\textit{\textbf{Result}}
    &        &    Win  & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sc}
\end{small}
\end{center}
```